# Функция принимает число n. Напишите рекурсивную функцию r1, которая выводит числа от n до нуля в out-1. Разделитель - пробел

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

```js
function t1(n) {
  let out = "";

  function r1(z) {
    for (let i = 0; i < z; i++) {
      document.querySelector(".out-1").innerHTML = i;
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector(".b-1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  t1(5);
});
```

не пойму, что принимает `r1` в качестве аргумента? Пример простой, но додумать не могу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тот самый n, до которого идёт вывод, и принимает.
Да вот только вывод будет, боюсь, не от n до 0, а от 0 до n.

ЗЫ: Я программы очень давно не писал, даже, что за язык это, не знаю:-)) Надеюсь, JavaScript. Так что ответ мой - скорее "на подумать" в данном направлении.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: это js, подумаю сам)
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: 1. Выводиться ничего не будет, поскольку функция r1 объявлена, но не вызывается. Зачем вообще в функции t1 объявлять еще одну функцию?

Comment: И еще,   насколько понимаю задание, требуется вывести ВСЕ числа, разделив их пробелами. Сейчас каждое новое число будет затирать предыдущее. Переменная out ведь не просто так была объявлена? Записываешь все числа с разделителями в переменную, а потом уже присваиваешь innerHTML значение этой переменной. Успехов! :)

Comment: Спасибо большое)